# Why does the conditional probability of an event share the same linear expression with the original probability?

Tags: probability

For example, let M, N, A, B be 4 events. Is it that $ \mathbb{P}(M\mid N)=\mathbb{P}(A\mid N)+\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(B\mid N) $ holds if $\mathbb{P}(M)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(B)$? If so, could anyone kindly explain? Furthermore, if the original probability $\mathbb{P}(M)$ could be expressed nonlinearly, would the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(M\mid N)$ remain the nonlinear expression with corresponding contional terms?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not. What if $A \cap N =B \cap N=\varnothing$, but simply $M =N$?

I do not understand the second question due to vague wording.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question comes from one exercise but now I realize that I misunderstood the solution.